# MYSQL comma separated result with two types

Tags: mysql

I have 4 tables, as below.

Table: **Class**

```
ClassID     |   ClassSTD
--------------------------------
1           |   STD-1
2           |   STD-2
3           |   STD-3
4           |   STD-4
```

Table: **Section**

```
SectionId   |   SectionName | ClassId
--------------------------------------------
1           |   sec-A       | 1
2           |   sec-B       | 1
3           |   sec-C       | 1
4           |   sec-A       | 2
5           |   sec-B       | 2
6           |   sec-C       | 2
7           |   sec-A       | 3
```

Table: **Subject**

```
subjectId   |   subjectName
------------------------------------
1           |   Art
2           |   Music
3           |   Play
```

Table **SubjectAllocationToClass**

```
classId     |   sectionID           |   subjectId   | type
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
1(STD-1)        |   1(sec-A)            |   1(Art)      | main
1(STD-1)        |   2(sec-B)            |   1(Art)      | main
1(STD-1)        |   3(sec-C)            |   1(Art)      | optional
1(STD-1)        |   1(sec-A)            |   2(Music)    | main
1(STD-1)        |   2(sec-B)            |   2(Music)    | optional
```

Above table "SubjectAllocationToClass" shows distribution of two type of subject (Main and optional) to section for class.

**Need All Class irrespective of section or subjectAllocation
Need All Section irrespective of subjectAllocation**

How I can achieve below result from SELECT statement?

```
    classSTD |  sectionName | Main subjectName   | Optional subjectName
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    STD-1    |  sec-A       | Art, Music         |
    STD-1    |  sec-B       | Art                |  Music
    STD-1    |  sec-C       |                    |  Art
    STD-3    |  sec-A       |                    |
    STD-4    |              |                    |
```

Comment: In the `SubjectAllocationToClass` table, are the values in the first 3 columns in the form shown (`1(STD-1)`, or was `(STD-1)` only added in the example?

Comment: In the SubjectAllocationToClass table,  (STD-1) for only for example. actual values are 1 instead of 1(STD-1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select 
  ClassSTD as ClassSTD, 
  sectionname AS SectionName, 
  COALESCE(GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN sac.type = 'main' THEN subjectName END), '')  as 'Main subjectname',
  COALESCE(GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN sac.type = 'optional' THEN subjectName END), '')  as 'Optional subjectname'
FROM SubjectAllocationToClass sac
JOIN  Class c  ON c.classid = sac.classid
JOIN Section sc ON sc.sectionid = sac.sectionid
JOIN Subject sj ON  sj.subjectid = sac.subjectid
GROUP BY ClassSTD, SectionName;
```

Comment: I tried putting Left and Full Join but not able to get it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `GROUP_CONCAT()` along with `CASE` expression to have a conditional grouping like below

```
select c.ClassID, s.sectionName,
xx.`Main subjectName`,
xx.`optional subjectName`
from Class c
join Section ss on c.ClassID  = ss.ClassID     
join (
select sa.sectionID,
group_concat(case when sa.type = 'main' then s.subjectName else null end) as  `Main subjectName`,
group_concat(case when sa.type = 'optional' then s.subjectName else null end) as  `optional subjectName`
from SubjectAllocationToClass sa
join Subject s on sa.subjectId = s.subjectId   
group by sa.subjectId ) xx on ss.SectionId = xx.SectionId;
```

Comment: it works, Can NULL be replace with "-" where no record found for a column ? also getting duplicate values in column. For example Art,Art, instead of Art

Comment: Yes you can using either `IFNULL()` or `COALESCE()` function. Again I have used inner join but based on your need you may choose to perform a LEFT JOIN instead.

Comment: also getting duplicate values in column. For example Art,Art, instead of Art.  I checked, table data. I looks fine. Any clue for duplicate values?

Comment: Yes, you can use `distinct` like `group_concat(case when sa.type = 'main' then distinct s.subjectName else null end)`. Play around try figuring out yourself to gain better understanding.